# CloudFlare page rule not caching as expected

Tags: cloudflare, http-caching

I'm serving up pages in the URL format of..

http://www.website.co.uk/234242/title-of-web-post

I'm trying to set it to cache everything for these posts using the page rule of

```
*website.co.uk/*/*
```

but looking at the analytics in cloud flare its only caching a small amount of requests.

Am I misunderstanding the syntax of the page rules? What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Edit: just to clarify...the below is my desired outcome

Cached

```
http://www.website.co.uk/432432/funny-cats
http://www.website.co.uk/234234/cool-trees
```

Not cached

```
http://www.website.co.uk
http://www.website.co.uk/sitemap.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to cache everything, or just stuff that is within a sub-folder?

Comment: What kind of figures are you seeing in analytics?

Comment: Cached Requests: 27 / 
Uncached Requests: 1,272 / 
Fewer Servers Needed: 2% / 
Bandwidth Saved: 1% / 
Content breakdown: HTML at 95%  -  stats for last 24 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks correct to me, unless that `/*/*` gives it trouble identifying the pattern correctly.

Do note that it keeps one cached copy per EDGE node, so you will still see one request for each EDGE node used to access your page. For a low-volume site, this can give you lower percentage of cached request than you expect.

The response headers that you receive from he request, indicates if the request is cached or not, especially with this header:

```
CF-Cache-Status:HIT
```

Which will show MISS if it wasn't cached at the EDGE node. If missed, subsequent request should respond with a HIT if the rules are setup correctly.

Comment: Ah thanks for that I didn't know Cloud Flare cache info was sent in the header. I just fired up fiddler and got CF-Cache-Status: MISS the first time then reloaded and got CF-Cache-Status: HIT the second time. So it looks like the rule is working! :-)

Comment: Another way to try and track down requests that might not be cached would be to run some aggregation-tool on your access logs. You can usually get a list of "top requests" which would give you paths that aren't cached properly very easily.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you will want to make 3 page rules, and they should be placed in the following order.

1. `http://www.website.co.uk` with CACHE LEVEL set to BYPASS
2. `http://www.website.co.uk/sitemap.txt` with CACHE LEVEL set to
   BYPASS
3. `http://www.website.co.uk/*` with CACHE LEVEL set to CACHE
   EVERYTHING

This may put you over your page rule limit, but you will soon be able to purchase additional page rules without upgrading plans.